make errors while trying to compile the apue.h source code
Trying to use apue.h for one of my c code and i am unable to compile and make apue.h
I first downloaded the apue.h source code
Then I unzipped the tar.gz file and entered the apue.3e directory.
Next I Ran the make command which threw this error :
gcc -shared -Wl,-dylib -o libapue_db.so.1 -L../lib -lapue -lc db.o
/usr/bin/ld: Error: unable to disambiguate: -dylib (did you mean --dylib ?)
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [Makefile:32: libapue_db.so.1] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/creative-mode/Downloads/src.3e/apue.3e/db'
make: *** [Makefile:6: all] Error 1

My make version :
GNU Make 4.3
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 1988-2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.


I tried it.
you could delete -Wl,-dylib in line 12 of db/Makefile,which seems to be used by MacOS compiler.
